# Auto Add Function Prototype

Tags: c++, function, prototype

Im working on a project and I had to create over 100 methods in c++, as most of you know if you create the methods in the cpp file you need to still declare it in the header file. It will be very time consuming to create over 100 declarations of all the methods, so I wanted to see if someone knew a quicker way. thank you.

Comment: ... What's your IDE?

Comment: write a shell script?

Comment: very suspicious - a need for 100+ methods in a class. Is it still cohesive? MAybe consider redesign or add some method template?

Comment: Copy paste of logic is usually handled with templates in C++. By the way, my ide create function definition for me.

Comment: @icaptan Meh! ...

Comment: im using visual studio.